# Flutter: Prevent `build` being called when `Refresher` is used

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-build

I am using the [pull_to_refresh](https://pub.dev/packages/pull_to_refresh) package.

I am having a `Stack()` with two elements. One of them is the `Refresher()`. When I pull down on my screen, activating the refreshing animation, the `build` method is called constantly. The problem is that my second Widget in my Stack is quite complex to build and takes some time. I want to prevent having it build all the time when triggering the `Refresher`-Animation. Is this possible?

My simplified code would look like this:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        body: Stack(children: <Widget>[
          SafeArea(
              child: Column(children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                  width: 100.w,
                  constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand(),
                  child: SizedBox(
                              width: 100.w,
                              child: Refresher( refresher stuff )
                              )
                          )
                      )
                  )
              ),
              SecondItem()
          )
      )
 }
```

Somehow the `build` method of `SecondItem` is called all the time. **Not** the `build` method of the whole scaffold.

Comment: The Refresher Widget shouldn't rebuild the entire screen unless `setState()` is called. Are you calling `setState()` when a refresh is done? If you'd like to update the children widgets displayed inside the Refresher, you may want consider using Streams. Then use `StreamBuilder` to only rebuild the widgets inside it when the Stream has changed. With this approach, you don't need to call `setState()` and the entire screen won't need to be rebuilt.

Comment: @Omatt the `build` is called during the pulldown of the animation which will trigger the refresh in the end. I am not able to call `setState()` while this happens.

Answer (score 0):

If Your second Item dont want to get refresh, then add it as a separeate class like,

```
 Expanded(
              child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                  width: 100.w,
                  constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand(),
                  child: SizedBox(
                              width: 100.w,
                              child: Refresher( refresher stuff )
                              )
                          )
                      )
                  )
              ),
              SecondItem()
          )


class SecondItem extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SecondItemState createState() => _SecondItemState();
}

class _SecondItemState extends State<SecondItem> {
  int counter = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Text("Your Second Widget"),
    );
  }
}
```

Now your SecondItem() **will not get refresh** when you refresh your FirstItem()

Comment: Actually it is an own stateful widget in a seperate class.

Comment: sorry bro @progNewbie, dont know

Answer (score 0):

Since I wasn't really able to replicate the problem, I build a working structure that implements refreshing.

First the main widget, in my case `MyHomePage`.
This widget implements the `Scaffold` and `Stack` with `FirstWidget` and `SecondWidget` as children.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: const <Widget>[
          FirstWidget(),
          SecondWidget(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`FirstWidget` is a `statefull` widget with a `counter` in the state.
It implements the `refresher` with a specific `controller`.
Once the refresh is triggered, it calls `set state` and updates the `counter` within his state.
That should trigger only his build again and not any other.
I implemented a `Text` to show the `counter` value increasing at each refresh, and a `Print` to expose the build.

```
class FirstWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const FirstWidget({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FirstWidget> createState() => _FirstWidgetState();
}

class _FirstWidgetState extends State<FirstWidget> {
  late int _counter;
  late RefreshController _refreshController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _counter = 1;
    _refreshController = RefreshController(initialRefresh: false);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('First widget built');
    return SafeArea(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 500,
            color: Colors.red,
            child: SmartRefresher(
              controller: _refreshController,
              onRefresh: () async {
                setState(() {
                  _counter++;
                });
                await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1000));
                _refreshController.refreshCompleted();
              },
            ),
          ),
          Text("Counter: $_counter"),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Last we got the `SecondWidget` which is a another simple widget with a `print` statement.
In case of build it writes on the console.
**When the `FirstWidget` refresh, the second doesn't build becouse his state has not changed**.

```
class SecondWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const SecondWidget({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SecondWidget> createState() => _SecondWidgetState();
}

class _SecondWidgetState extends State<SecondWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('Second widget built');
    return const Center(child: Text('Second here!'));
  }
}
```

**Possible cause of your problem.**

It could be that when refreshing, you actually are updating the state of a parent widget that, on cascade, causes the re build of your second widget.
If state is handled correctly, and your second widget doesn't depends on your first widget state, the refresh should not rebuild the second.

Comment: Thank you for your effort! I don't understand why it is not working for me. I am not updating the state of a parent widget while the refreshing anmiation is done. I mean not even `onRefresh` is loaded while this happens, so how could I reload the parent widget.

Comment: There must be some relation that causes the build to be triggered inside the second widget. Could you try replacing the second widget with the one I've provided? In that way we can exclude that the problem is caused by your second widget

Comment: Another problem is the onRefresh which is not getting called, that means that probably even the same refreshing widget gets rebuilt, which is not ok.
The 'refresh' widget should only rebuild his child and not itself

Comment: Have you got any updates?